# JQuery Slidetoggle() working but not how I need it too

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

It's kind of hard to explain, but I have these rows, about 22 of them, and when I click a row, a content panel section should slide down and reveal it, and then when I click the row again, it should hide it. At the moment click to reveal works, but if I click the content panel that slides down it slides back up,

I only want it so if i click the row again it slides back up and if i click the content that slid down, nothing to happen, so that people can click links and stuff in it, without it closing.

Here is some of my code.
JQUERY:

```
var main = function() {

$(".article").click(function() {
    $('.article').removeClass('current');
       $(this).addClass('current');
       $(this).children('.description').slideToggle();
}); 
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Heres the HTML, just 1 row, of 22:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="articles container">
      <div class="article">
          <div class="item row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                  <p class="source">Content</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <p class="title">"Content"</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                  <p class="pubdate">Content</p>
              </div>
         </div>
         <div class="description row">
             <div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
                 <p>Content</p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>
             </div>
        </div>
     <div>
     </body>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="example.js"></script>
     <html>
```

and here is the accompanying css: not including the bootstrap ones i'm using.

```
.articles {
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.article {
color: white;
background: black;
border-spacing: 10px;
border-color: black;
font-family: arial,sans-serif;
border-bottom: 5px #e5e5e5 solid;
}

.current .item {
background: grey;
}

.item {
cursor: pointer;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.item .source {
margin-left: 20px;
}

.item .title {
font-weight: bold;
}   

.item .pubdate {
margin-right: 20px;
}

.item .pubdate {
text-align: right;  
}

.description {
display: none;
padding-bottom: 5px;
background: black;
}
```

I think this is the only relevant code for the problem:

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
var main = function() {

$(".article").click(function() {
    $('.article').not($(this)).removeClass('current');
    if($(this).hasClass('current')){
        // if this clicked before and has class current already
        // in second click
       // code here
    }else{
       // if this first click 
       $(this).addClass('current');
       // code here
    }   
}); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would re-factor your html so it has a button like handle.

HTML

```
<article>
<span>Show/Hide</span>
<div class="dropdown" style="display:none;">
    // content to display on toggle
</div>
</article>
```

JS / JQUERY

```
$('article span')on('click', function(){ $('.dropdown').slideToggle('fast'); };
```